# ofxCvImage.h file have list of errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, openframeworks

I am working with openFrameworks based project. The version of openFrameworks is https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks
[for more info](http://openframeworks.cc/download/)

But the problem is when i add the project in openFramework library i got list of errors in ofxCvImage.h file".
I updated the recommended setting in xcode and Build Active Architecture Only to No.

[image]

Please help me to solve this.Suggest me if i have to change some paths.

Comment: have you try like, #include <ofMain.h> ?

Comment: Yes it also give same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you check last marge and commit for the project , you can notice that

**Remove ofMain.h where appropriate since it is included in ofApp.h templates.**

Check Out

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/pull/4675

Comment: Now in ofApp.h if i remove ofMain.h then other included files getting not found like ofxiOS.h etc..

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya make sure you using last and recent version

Comment: in my question i specify both the version links on GitHub and official site of Frameworks also please check and suggest if i am going wrong.